# Access element being hovered over with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a section with three articles inside of it. When I hover over each article, I want the appropriate text within that article to slide over by 20px, however the article is positioned in a way that the text is aligned alongside the left edge, but I want to be able to have the text slide over no matter where in that specific article my mouse is on.

I have a JS function, but how do I access the specific article that is being hovered over? How can I do that with Javascript? (Not jQuery)

I currently have a div as shown by the jsfiddle linked below. I want the text to slide over when my mouse hovers over any part of the blue box, even though the text does not span the entire width.

https://jsfiddle.net/g8nzcurf/

```
#test{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
}

#text{
  width:50px;
}


<div id="test">
  <div id="text">
    This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the `:hover` pseudo-class. Otherwise, share your **existing code** and detail any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned by Obsidian Age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662712/access-element-being-hovered-over-with-javascript#comment90288948_51662712), you can use the `:hover` pseudo-class to select things when they're hovered. You can combine it with a descendant combinator to selectively apply styles to other elements when certain conditions are met. In this case, you could use `.article:hover .text` for your needs.

**Edit:** As @Kaiido mentioned, you can use pseudo-classes with querySelectors. So in a mouseenter event, you could use `document.querySelector('.article:hover .text')` to select the relevant text div, like in the following snippet:

```js
var articleDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.article');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < articleDivs.length; i++) {
  articleDivs[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function (e) {
    var textDiv = document.querySelector('.article:hover .text');
    // do something with the div
    console.log(textDiv);
  });
}
```

```css
.article {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.text{
  width:50px;
  color: #ddd;
}

.article:hover .text {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <div class="text">
    This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="article">
  <div class="text">
    This is also a test. This is also a test. This is also a test.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since OP was asking specifically about js, there should probably be a note that `querySelector` also accepts the `:hover` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your update example, and the comment below, you'd want to put a class on those types of elements you'd want to hover over, so I'm updating the querySelector.  You should probably use CSS like the people prompting you to provide code are suggesting, but since you asked for JS I'll update it a little bit in case you're more interested in learning and experimenting.

You can add an event listener to the elements using `mouseover` event and change the style there.  You might all want to add a `mouseleave` event to style it back.  Here's a quick example below that does exactly that to all `div`s on the page with a class of `hover` attached (not id's for this example!).

```
<!-- html -->
<div class="hover"></div><div class="hover"></div>



const hoverDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.hover');
hoverDivs.forEach((div)=>{
div.addEventListener('mouseover',(event)=>{
    div.style.left = "-20px"
})
div.addEventListener('mouseleave',(event)=>{
    div.style.left = "0px";
});
```

});

But it sounds like if your looking for a solution, you should probably just use CSS.  It's bad practice to style stuff inline like that with JS or HTML.  If anything you should be adding and removing classes on moveover, and then your style sheet should refer to those classes to handle something like changing how it looks.  In that event you wouldn't do div.style.left, you'd do the vanilla js equivalent of adding and removing a class.  So instead of `div.style.left = '-20px'`... you'd do:

```
 div.classList.add('hovered-over');
```

And have some css that was such (also not great CSS):

```
.hovered-over { left: -20px }
```

Since this is just a mental exercise at this point and you probably should use CSS if you're looking for the proper approach I won't show how to remove a class.  The answer is out there, but if you're trying to get this particular thing accomplished it CSS has it covered and is the proper place to deal with it in most cases.

Comment: Now nest several divs for some funky junk.

Comment: Oh, he updated his example with some code, now there are ids, there was no code before.  His id's should be classes, and I was just using generic divs as an example of how to do it.  He had nothing before just a question for how to do it with javascript.  I guess I'll update my answer to reflect his code or maybe SO can do it cause I'm lazy atm.  This works fine though so long as your not applying it to generic elements such as divs.  He asked for a JS type solution to open ended question.  The querySelector's up to him, absent the details.

Comment: I'm not really sure though how to go about refitting this in the context of his question though now that the people who want to solve his specific problem using CSS made him provide code examples when he asked a generic js question, and that's kind of what this answer is.  Feels like the CSS stuff isn't actually answering his question.

Comment: Definitely not best practice, just answering his question as it was framed.  Maybe I should just delete this even if this question goes to CSS, this will never be the definitive question on this topic lol.  he should probably be using css for this

Comment: Everyone should try getting funky with javascript, now and then.

Comment: What I meant is that mouseover will bubble to the parents, so if you are listening to both parent and children mouseover events, you'll receive a lot of these.

Comment: Yeah, in an ideal world he'd give the divs he wanted the proper class. I think I can update this without getting too meta.  Thanks

Comment: I tried looking into it with CSS as well, however, I was unable to figure out how to manipulate the text when the mouse was hovering over another portion of the div that did not embody the text, and was unsure how to select the appropriate text to transition. I guess even now my question was incomplete, but essentially, I have multiple divs within a container that share properties, but are different colors and have different text, so I know I have to use the "this" keyword somewhere, but am not sure how to do so properly

Comment: And by my inclusion of "Javascript only", I meant without any frameworks or libraries, as I know this can be done with jQuery, etc., however I wanted to avoid using them, and wanted to understand how to perform these relatively simple animations with html, css and javascript alone, but perhaps I should have clarified a lot more in my initial question.

Comment: Sure, this doesn't use jquery, it uses vanilla javascript.  It'll run in your console in the browser, if your intention is to learn/improve about vanilla JS to rather than solve some actual problem, I'll provide a tip - try using the debugger and setting a breakpoint where the code handles the event and sets the style.  Really none of our answers are great solutions to the problem you have.  You probably don't need any javascript at all.  The accepted answer is better than this, but if you're trying to get something specific done use CSS alone it sounds like